# sparse column or DATA_COMPRESSION?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, compression, sparse-column, query-performance

in one of my databases I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [app].[applicantSkill](
    [ApplicantSkillID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [applicantID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [skillID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [skillDetails] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [skillLevelID] [tinyint] SPARSE  NULL,
    [dateAdded] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [lastModified] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_applicant_skill] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ApplicantSkillID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [UserFG],
 CONSTRAINT [uc_appSkillID] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [applicantID] ASC,
    [skillID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [UserFG]
) ON [UserFG]
GO
```

which has 1 [sparse column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-2017) - `skillLevelID`

when I have to re-create my index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX I_applicantID  
ON [app].[applicantSkill] (  [applicantID] ASC  , [dateAdded] ASC  )  
INCLUDE ( [ApplicantSkillID] , [skillDetails] , [skillID] , [skillLevelID])  WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF, FILLFACTOR = 100  , SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, 
STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, DATA_COMPRESSION=PAGE, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON ) ON [NONCLUSTERED_INDEXES]
```

I get the following error message:

```
Msg 10622, Level 16, State 1, Line 18
The index 'I_applicantID' could not be created or rebuilt. A compressed index is not supported on table that contains sparse columns or a column set column.
```

How can I find out which one `the sparse column or the data_compression` should I keep?

Comment: What is your goal for using a sparse column or compression? What's the average length of the values stored in the 'skillDetails' field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the MS documentation, there is [a chart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-sparse-columns?view=sql-server-2017#estimated-space-savings-by-data-type) to estimate space savings for sparse columns.

According to said chart, if at least 86% of the values are NULL, you will have an overall savings of at least 40% for this column. Each `TINYINT` value is going to take up 5 bytes versus the normal 1 byte in this scenario.

You can compare this with the compression savings by using [sp_estimate_data_compression_savings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-estimate-data-compression-savings-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for the proposed index.

This should give you enough information to make an informed decision about which is the right approach.

Resources:

- [sp_sizeoptimiser](http://expressdb.io/sp_sizeoptimiser/) Uses statistics to automatically recommend changing a column to sparse if it meets the threshold to reclaim at least 40% space. *Disclaimer: I wrote it!*

Comment: I could not find the `sp_sizeoptimiser` have you changed the link?

Comment: you have lots of good sql stuff, specially sql express  on your page, I recommend it!

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli Oops, looks like I need to fix that URL. Thanks for the headsup