# how to find tables with either sparse or a column set column?

Tags: sql-server, index, disk-space, compression, sparse-column

from the error message below:

> A compressed index is not supported on table that contains sparse
>   columns or a column set column

as I was [rebuilding an index](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/244899/22336) and changing the `data_compression` to page

This was after making good use of [sparse column or compression data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/220479/22336) wonderful scripts.

**Question:**

what are `column set columns` and how to find tables with either sparse or a column set column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the [`sys.columns`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) table:

```
SELECT name, is_sparse, is_column_set 
FROM sys.columns
```

[Column sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-column-sets?view=sql-server-2017) are:

> Tables that use sparse columns can designate a column set to return all sparse columns in the table. A column set is an untyped XML representation that combines all the sparse columns of a table into a structured output. A column set is like a calculated column in that the column set is not physically stored in the table. A column set differs from a calculated column in that the column set is directly updatable.